# SUM(ATR * QTDE) / SUM(QTDE) is the same as SUM(ATR)?

Tags: sql

## Background:

My boss just send me a query with the following column

```
ROUND(SUM(ATR * QTDE) / SUM(QTDE), 2)
```

But then I thought isn't it the same as

```
ROUND(SUM(ATR), 2)
```

??

If it was just `ATR * QTDE / QTDE` I would be certain that it's the same, but with the `SUM` I'm not sure, looks the same, but I can't just use what I think it's the same without been certain of it. Also I don't want to question my boss about it, so... here I'm!

## Question:

`SUM(ATR * QTDE) / SUM(QTDE)` is the same as `SUM(ATR)` ?

## Wanted results:

Explanation and prove of why it's the same or it's different.

Comment: Not the same. Consider the case one single row, ATR = 1, QTDE = 0.

Comment: Why not just try both? You would find out very quickly.

Comment: @jarlh would that be division by zero or 1?

Comment: @JNevill I tried, looks the same with the data I have here, but I can't be sure only with some rows and not all cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't the same!

If you try with sample data you can see it ...

```
ATR QTDE
5   1
5   2

SUM(ATR) = 5 + 5 = 10


SUM(ATR * QTDE) / SUM(QTDE) = (5*1 + 5*2) / (1 + 2) = 15 / 3 = 5
```

Comment: All caps is the equivalent of shouting. Please be nice.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same.  One is a weighted average and the other is just a sum.  It is easy to devise counter 
 examples.

```
ATR   QTDE
 1    100
 2    200
```

SUM(ATR) = 3.  The ratio returns 500 / 3 <> 3.

You are probably thinking that these are equivalent:

```
ROUND(SUM(ATR * QTDE) / SUM(QTDE), 2) 

ROUND(AVG(ATR), 2)
```

That would only be true if `SUM(QTDE) = COUNT(ATR)` -- which would normally happen if your data is set up this way or if `QTDE = 1`.